# Basic HTTP Auth in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a smallish Yesod application (using the scaffold). I'd like to add basic HTTP authentication to all requests. Here's what I tried so far:

- I've read the docs on Yesod authentication, but there's unfortunately no backend supporting this.
- `isAuthorized` would be great, but I can't see a way to read the headers there.
- A WAI middleware would be elegant, but I can't find any documentation describing how to use one with a full Yesod application. It's also pretty clear that writing one is not completely trivial.

Was this already done? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've come up with a non-ideal solution: I prepend an action to all my handler functions. Maybe it'll be useful for someone, maybe someone can improve upon this. Here's the code:

```
httpBasicAuth :: Handler ()
httpBasicAuth = do
  request <- waiRequest
  case lookup "Authorization" (requestHeaders request) of
    Just "Basic base64encodedusernameandpassword" -> return ()
    _ -> do
      setHeader "WWW-Authenticate" "Basic Realm=\"My Realm\""
      permissionDenied "Authentication required"
```

And using it:

```
fooR :: Handler ()
fooR = httpBasicAuth >> do
  sendResponseStatus status200 ()
```

I'll be more than happy to move the "accepted" checkmark if a better solution is posted.

Comment: Upvoted because I just might have to do something like this myself and your example was the only thing I could find thus far.

Comment: Its been awhile since this question was asked, but since this is a top result on google for "yesod http basic auth" I wanted to point people to http://stackoverflow.com/q/24770415/1176156 which explains how to use the WAI middleware to do HTTP basic auth.