# yesod -- password protecting staging site

Tags: authentication, haskell, passwords, yesod

I'm trying to set up a staging instance of my yesod webserver, and I was wondering if there were some easy way to make the entire site password protected. Specifically, I want to be able to prompt those who navigate to my site for credentials. After they authenticate it should function as the typical site. But if they cannot authenticate themselves they should see nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on @MichaelSnoyman's answer, here's how I implemented the WAI HTTP Auth middleware:

From the scaffolded site, I went to `Application.hs`, which has already setup some logging middleware like so:

```
makeApplication :: AppConfig DefaultEnv Extra -> IO Application
makeApplication conf = do
    foundation <- makeFoundation conf

    -- Initialize the logging middleware
    logWare <- mkRequestLogger def
        { outputFormat =
            if development
                then Detailed True
                else Apache FromSocket
        , destination = RequestLogger.Logger $ loggerSet $ appLogger foundation
        }

    -- Create the WAI application and apply middlewares
    app <- toWaiAppPlain foundation
    return $ logWare app
```

To add HTTP auth, I referenced the Yesod book's [chapter on WAI](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/web-application-interface) and the [HttpAuth docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-HttpAuth.html) that Michael referenced. The docs give this as an example of using the HttpAuth middleware:

```
basicAuth (\u p -> return $ u == "michael" && p == "mypass") "My Realm"
```

I was able to just paste that at the bottom right after the logging middleware is applied:

```
import qualified Network.Wai.Middleware.HttpAuth as HttpAuth

makeApplication :: AppConfig DefaultEnv Extra -> IO Application
makeApplication conf = do
    foundation <- makeFoundation conf

    -- Initialize the logging middleware
    logWare <- mkRequestLogger def
        { outputFormat =
            if development
                then Detailed True
                else Apache FromSocket
        , destination = RequestLogger.Logger $ loggerSet $ appLogger foundation
        }

    -- Create the WAI application and apply middlewares
    app <- toWaiAppPlain foundation
    return $ logWare $ HttpAuth.basicAuth (\u p -> return $ u == "michael" && p == "mypass") "My Realm" $ app
```

Here's what that looks like in Safari:

[image: HTTP auth browser screenshot]

This kind of authentication isn't really appropriate for regular users, but its great for locking down a site meant for internal use. Its also an easy way for machines (monitoring servers, scripts) to authenticate themselves with your server.

Comment: Wow, I knew there must be an easy answer. Here it is! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the http auth middleware.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.1/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-HttpAuth.html

Sorry for brevity, on a mobile.

Comment: If you are already fronting the site with Ngnix or Apache, they can do HTTP auth before calling your yesod site, too.  (I always end up using one of the fcgi-type wai interfaces under Apache, but it's been a while.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused as to how to use the provided code within the yesod framework. How should I use/activate this code, and how would I make it prompt for authentiction (i.e. the user/pass test/test)?